`package.json` and node_modules not found
I can't find package.json and node modules folder after running yarn add --dev hardhat

Could you give more detail about your issue? You mean you init your node project before, and after yarn add the package.json + node modules were deleted?

In the root of your project try running  npm init then
npm install and check for package.json it should be at the root of the project.
let me know if it helps.
